# marker is not an rvalue in logback

Tags: java, logback, spring-logback, logback-classic

I have this filter in my logback-spring.xml:

```xml
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
    <evaluator>
        <expression>
            return marker instanceof com.package.logging.Metrics.Marker;
        </expression>
    </evaluator>
    <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    <onMismatch>NEUTRAL</onMismatch>
</filter>
```

the filter has been working until I started upgrading my dependencies. Here's a list of the most relevant upgrades:

- Java 8 -> 17
- Spring boot 2.5 -> 3.0.8
- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.11 -> 1.4.11
- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11 -> 1.4.11
- org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.1.7 -> 3.1.10

Now it's giving me this error on application startup:

> ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator@40d10481 - Could not start evaluator with expression [return marker instanceof com.package.logging.Metrics.Marker;] org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: Line 2, Column 8: Expression "marker" is not an rvalue

Comment: @Spring this is what I've done so far but I haven't tested it https://gist.github.com/dev-rifaii/c32912ccdffc4c544a3417f89ed289be
I will post an answer if this solution works properly or if I find another

Comment: Please share your codebase

Answer (score 1):

Issue arises due to the deprecated getMarker() Method:

https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/ILoggingEvent.html

This is how I solved in my case:

old expression:

```
  <expression>return marker != null &amp;&amp; marker.getName().equals("FUNC");</expression>
```

changed to:

```
  <expression>return event.getMarkerList() != null &amp;&amp; !event.getMarkerList().isEmpty() &amp;&amp; ((org.slf4j.Marker) event.getMarkerList().get(0)).getName().equals("FUNC");</expression>
```